# Android standard brace style legality

Tags: java, android, coding-style

Reading [this piece of information](http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html#use-standard-brace-style), it states that:

> We require braces around the
>   statements for a conditional. Except,
>   if the entire conditional (the
>   condition and the body) fit on one
>   line, you may (but are not obligated
>   to) put it all on one line. That is,
>   this is legal:

```
if (condition) {
    body(); 
}
```

> and this is legal:

```
if (condition) body();
```

> but this is still **illegal**:

```
if (condition)
    body();  // bad!
```

Why is the last mentioned bad? It is a mix of the two above, but what is the motivation for **not** using that kind of style? IMO, it is the most readable (or equaly readable to the first one).

I know that may not apply to Android specifically, but it's the first place I've heard about it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the code you have that is bad style, you have a problem with languages that don't use indentation to determine what to do with the code. Imagine I'm maintaining your code and see this:

```
if (condition)
    body();  // bad!
```

I decide to add a line to it, to make it this:

```
if (condition)
    body();  // bad!
    myconditionalfcn(); // Will always execute
```

The other two styles you have prevent this mistake, one by making the entire conditional a single line, and the other by ensuring I enter my new function inside the braces.

When working on someone else's project, you should never break their style. When working on your own project, you should strive for readability in your style--the problem with the second, in terms of readability, is that it can cause confusion like the above. A good editor will let you auto-correct this error, but it's (almost) always better to avoid it in the first place by not having single line conditionals split like that.

Comment: Actually `if (condition) body(); myconditionalfcn();` (all on one line) is just as bad.  A truly robust coding style demands braces on every block of code.

Comment: @Edwin Not all styles demand braces on every block of code (my personal style does, but that's besides the point). Having that all on one line *is* just as bad, but it would break any good style, since then you have two commands on one line. And it also wouldn't do what you'd expect it to do reading the code--again myconditionalfcn() would be executed always. `if (condition) body();` is fine because it makes it clear that in order to extend the code executed when `condition` is true, you must add the braces yourself. As a rule of thumb, semicolons in code should be followed by a newline.

Comment: @Dylnuge, I didn't say that the style doesn't exist, I just said it wasn't robust.  Robustness is the ability for the exact meaning to be transmitted despite the environment, not what people prefer at the current moment.  And yes, I've been programming long enough that I've even seen some styles go out-of-style which were, well popular, but horrid (like Hungarian notation applied to Java).

Comment: @Edwin I don't disagree; using one line conditionals can introduce issues. However, it is still a *different* style issue to have two statements on the same line. If your statements are always on separate lines, one line conditionals rarely introduce readability issues, whereas broken line conditionals often cause problems down the road. What I disagree with is your claim that the one-liner is "just as bad."

Comment: @Dylnuge, The compiler just sees a stream of tokens, so the one line style with no braces is (to the compiler's eyes) exactly the same as the multi-line style with no braces.  As far as disagreeing with my opinion stating that it is "just as bad", well, that's why it's called an opinion.

Comment: @Edwin I'm confused--when did we start talking about compilers? Of course coding style doesn't matter to the compiler; that's not what coding style is *about*. By that argument I could put all my code on one line--after all, it's all the same to the compiler. And yeah, coding style is generally a matter of opinion.

Comment: @Dylnuge, Eventually, when everyone agrees that a particular style is better, the compiler enforces it.  For example, early FORTRAN programs used to "auto assign" type based on the first letter of the variable.  Shops eventually decided that good style was to explicitly specify the type, regardless of the auto-assignment.  Now FORTRAN doesn't even offer the auto-assignment.  Maybe it will eventually be like that with curly braces, maybe not.

Comment: @Edwin That's hardly the same thing. Compilers enforce syntax, not style, and your story is an example of evolving syntax, not evolving style (though I admit, the line between the two is blurry--for example whitespace in Java is a matter of style, but in Python, a matter of syntax). Again, the compiler won't prevent me from putting all my code on one line, even though it is *universally* regarded as horrible style.

Comment: @Dylnuge, actually if you study the evolution of programming language constructs, it's easy to see a future where it would be impossible to put all of your code on one line.  Python's indentation requirements get pretty close, although you can use the ternary operator in a pinch.

Comment: @Edwin In another language, yes. Not in Java. Therefore, the compiler won't evolve so much as future languages may. Again, where did we get onto compilers and how they process code? You brought it up but I still have no idea why/where it came from.

Answer (score 3):

It does not apply to Android specifically. Like all indentation issue, is a question of tastes. Anyway using :

```
if (condition)
    body();  // bad!
```

could confuse someone reading fast the code, because it may be not clear where the condition statement ends.
Personally I prefer the first style:

```
if (condition) {
    body(); 
}
```

For the following reasons:

1. it isn't ambiguous at all
2. With nowadays IDEs (like Eclipse) is even fast to write using auto-completion
3. It's faster to add other statements inside the brackets, and often you will need to do this.

Comment: While I agree with the 3rd last points. How fast can one possibly read code and not see that the single execution below the if-statement depends on the evaluation (given that correct indentation style is used)?

Comment: @Whirlin: the @Dylnuge's answer show exactly what I meant. Anyway, it's not an error use the conditional without brackets, just a matter of taste as I've said.

Answer (score 3):

Coding styles are guidelines, what is legal is what the language definition permits.

When they use the term **legal** in respect to coding styles, they just mean what they will accept.  The example

```
if (condition)
  body();
```

is specifically singled out as it confuses indentation with execution, something that isn't actually part of the Java language specification.  In other words, someone might look at

```
if (condition)
  statement1();
  statement2();
```

and think that both statement1 and statement2 are executed only when the condition is true.  Note that this person would have made a mental mistake; a good coding style tries to minimize the number of mental mistakes which could occur in other people's minds.

Whether it is correct to permit

```
if (condition) statement1();
```

is open to debate.  For many this is acceptable; however, it is really subject to the same issue as the above example.  Java doesn't make decisions based on the type or amount of white space, it makes decisions based on the presence of any white space.  In other words, you could confuse someone by doing this

```
if (condition) statement1(); statement2();
```

where statement2 is always executed; hoping to confuse them into believing that statement2's execution is somehow dependent on the condition.  The reason that

```
if (condition) statement1();
```

is generally accepted has a lot to do with the extremely rare practice of seeing statements like

```
if (condition) statement1(); statement2();
```

but accepting the non-curly brace version has nothing to do with actually improving the code quality, it's just sometimes accepted because generally people don't write confusing "all-in-one-line" if statements.

With if statements, the only safe way to make sure that people don't associate behavior with white space is to always insert curly braces.

```
if (condition) { statement1(); } statement2();
```

may look odd, but it is guaranteed to provide enough visual cues that a person won't make a mental mistake of thinking that statement2's execution depends on statement1.

Finally,

```
if (condition) {
  statement1();
}
statement2();
```

will never confuse anyone.  The only possible cost is the storage of a few extra white space characters and the addition of a couple of horizontal typed lines.  Considering how much storage is available, I would say the storage argument is finally dead.  The screen real estate argument still remains; but, sometimes forcing an idea to be clear is worth a few extra lines on the screen (and screens are much larger today than they were in the past).  When one considers the cost of wasted manpower in pursing "wrong ideas" due to "mental mistakes" in reading code; it seems that a few extra curly braces here or there can pay for themselves nicely.

Besides, if you are using tons of if statements back to back, you probably would be better off using a switch or polymorphism.

Comment: Good read, but looking at your second piece of code, I think the actual problem there is indentation and not the lack of curly braces.

Comment: @Whirlwin The indentation problems stem from allowing the lack of braces in the first place--the point is that someone can add this very easily by mistake, *especially* in codebases that consist of both a whitespace delimited language like Python and a non-whitespace one like Java. Including the braces, or using a one-liner, removes the possibility of accidentally adding another line and thinking it executes. As Edwin said, "good coding style tries to minimize the number of mental mistakes which could occur."

Comment: @Whirlwin, The Java language specification says exactly nothing about indentation.  So from the language's point of view, indentation doesn't exist.  People use indentation to "annotate" their language in ways the compiler doesn't process.  So if you mis-annotate, it's like stating a falsehood in a comment.  It only serves to misdirect people reading the code.  Since curly braces are viewed by the compiler, it is impossible to misdirect the meaning as doing so would generate a compiler error.  Note that this doesn't imply in languages that do have compiler rules for whitespace, like Python.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, when talking about code formatting there cannot ever be used words like "legal" and "illegal". Illegal in my mind is something that acts harmful above your application. Right or bad formatting cannot cause your program to fail, formatting is simply a way to make your code readable. If you're working in a team you should consider using right formatting to make your teammates understand your code. When you're working alone it doesn't matter, you can write whatever you like with your own formatting style. That's just my opinion.

P.S. I personally use only the first style, it helps preventing silly mistakes.

Comment: There is a question of 'legal' or 'illegal' if they enforce a coding standard for an open source project where they're getting thousands of developers contributing source code.  Read the article the OP linked to carefully - or at least the title.  It says, "Code Style Guidelines for Contributors"

Comment: I think it is legal/illegal according to *best practice* , not the actual code itself.

Comment: The article isn't about _best practice_ its about code styles that will be rejected from their project.  Legal = accepted upstream, Illegal = rejected.

Comment: @Chris, thanks I've updated the question's title accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Personal code style preference combined with a strict adherence to style standards for contributing to their project.

If you've no interest in committing any code to AOSP I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Answer (score 0):

For readability, I prefer

```
if (conditiontest) doOneThing();
```

over either of these

```
if (conditiontest) { doOneThing(); }

if (conditiontest) {
     doOneThing();  }

if (conditiontest) { 
     doOneThing(); 
     }
```

This mostly just my opinion.  But I think it enhances it's succinctness.